# automapper collection convert create base class property

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

```
public class BaseEntity

{

​   Public Int Id{get;set;}

​   Public DateTime CreateTime{get;set;}

​   Public DateTime UpdateTime{get;set;}

}

public class EntityA:BaseEntity

{

​   Public string PropA{get;set;}

}

Public class BaseEntityDto

{

​   Public Int Id{get;set;}

}

public class EntityADto:BaseEntityDto

{

​   Public string PropA{get;set;}

}
```

my automapper profile

```
CreateMap<EntityA, EntityDto>().ReverseMap();
```

I create a record that can contain Id, CreateTime，UpdateTime property

i need get entity by id then update entity

```
var entity = await _projectionEventRepository.FindAsync(w => w.Id == dto.Id);
var newentity = Mapper.Map<EntityADto, EntityA>(dto, entity); 
entity{Code:"100",CreateTime:"20222-1-30",UpdateTime:"2022-1-30"}
dto{Code:"101"}
ok result newentity{Code:"101",CreateTime:"20222-1-30",UpdateTime:"2022-1-30"}
```

but now I create a list that can't contain CreateTime，UpdateTime property, how to changed it.

i need getlist by id then update entity

```
var entitylist = await _projectionEventRoleRepository.FindAllAsync(w => w.ProjectionEventId == dto.Id);
var newentitylist = Mapper.Map<List<EntityADto>, List<EntityA>>(dtolist, entitylist);
entitylist{Code:"100",CreateTime:"20222-1-30",UpdateTime:"2022-1-30",...}
dtolist{Code:"101"，...}
ok result newentity{Code:"101",CreateTime:"2022-1-30",UpdateTime:"2022-1-30",...}
now result newentity{Code:"101",CreateTime:"",UpdateTime:"",...}
```

At present, creating an entity dto can contain Id, CreateTime, and UpdateTime properties and value. When I need to map a collection, dtolist can also automatically create Id, CreateTime, and UpdateTime properties.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse mapping in AutoMapper (mapping a DTO onto an existing entity object) needs to be done individually rather than on a collection. AutoMapper does not have a mechanism to identify which source element belongs on which target element - it is outside the scope of the tool. You need to find the match and pass the matched pair to AutoMapper.

You can use a loop to iterate over the DTO collection, select the corresponding entity if one exists, and then perform the update mapping.

```
foreach(var dto in dtolist)
{
    var match = entitylist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == dto.Id);
    if (match == null)
        continue;
    Mapper.Map<EntityADto, EntityA>(dto, match);
}
```

Comment: i need getlist by id from database then merge id,createtime,updatetime,update entitylist

Comment: @beiduoan - I've posted updated code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Can I achieve my needs using AutoMapper.Collection https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229945/15869452

Comment: according to your plan match：{CreateTime:"2022-1-30"} dto：{CreateTime:"0001-01-01"} var newentity =Mapper.Map<EntityADto, EntityA>(dto, match); newentity：{CreateTime:"0001-01-01"}The CreateTime attribute cannot be assigned a value