# Problem Updating Table Data Using AutoMapper Map

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

**Problem Updating Table Data Using AutoMapper Map**.....
I Have Table ItemCategory When I try to Update table  it updates but only the EnterUserId Column Have Problem When it Null then Update and When Not Null then it makes it Null

My ItemCategory Table Class

```html
 public class ItemCategory
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }           
        public string CategNameE { get; set; }
        public string CategNameP { get; set; }           
        public DateTime EnterDate { get; set; }
        public string EntryStatus { get; set; }
        public string EnterUserID { get; set; }

        public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
        public bool IsDelete { get; set; }

    }
```

Update Code

```html
using Domain.Inv;

namespace Application.MasterEntry.Category
{
    public class Edit
    {
        public class Command : IRequest<Result<Unit>>
        {
            public ItemCategory ItemCategory { get; set; }
        }
        public class CommandValidator : AbstractValidator<ItemCategory>
        {
            public CommandValidator()
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.CategNameE).NotEmpty();
            }
        }
        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command, Result<Unit>>
        {
            private readonly DataContext _context;
            private readonly IUserAccessor _userAccessor;
            private readonly IMapper _mapper;

            public Handler(DataContext context, IUserAccessor userAccessor, IMapper mapper)
            {
                _mapper = mapper;
                _userAccessor = userAccessor;
                _context = context;

            }

            public async Task<Result<Unit>> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var category = await _context.ItemCategories.FindAsync(request.ItemCategory.CategoryID);

                if (category == null) return null;

                var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == _userAccessor.GetUsername());



                request.ItemCategory.EnterUserID = user.Id;
                request.ItemCategory.EnterDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                request.ItemCategory.EntryStatus = "Updated";

                _mapper.Map(request.ItemCategory, category);



                var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

                if (!result) return Result<Unit>.Failure("Faild to update category");

                return Result<Unit>.Success(Unit.Value);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping Profile Code

```html
namespace Application.Core
{
    public class MappingProfiles : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<ItemCategory, CategoryDto>();//Use For Listing The Data

            CreateMap<ItemCategory, ItemCategory>();
           
        }
    }
}
```

Category Dto Class

```html
  public class CategoryDto
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }          
        public string CategNameE { get; set; }
        public string CategNameP { get; set; }            
    }
```

Comment: Have you registered your mapping profile?

Comment: yes MappingProfiles

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping need to modify mapping.

```
 public MappingProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<ItemCategory, CategoryDto>();//Use For Listing The Data

        CreateMap<ItemCategory, ItemCategory>();
       
    }
```

It should be something like.

```
CreateMap<InputModelClass, EntityClass>();//replace with your model
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60672060

[Use AutoMapper for adding, updating and removing items in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220057/use-automapper-for-adding-updating-and-removing-items-in-list)